# Apply add/remove class to specific tag Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have one menu list like this..

```
            </div>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li id="About">@Html.ActionLink(@MvcWebRole1.Resources.Shared.Layout.About, "About", "Home")</li>
                <li id="Services">@Html.ActionLink(@MvcWebRole1.Resources.Shared.Layout.Services, "Services", "Home")</li>
                <li id="Partners">@Html.ActionLink(@MvcWebRole1.Resources.Shared.Layout.Partners, "Partners", "Home")</li>
.....
.....
```

And i want to add/remove a class to a specific tag when i click on a button with a jquery function..

How can i apply this one to a specific menu>li>id="About"??

I have tried something like this but it doesn't work..

```
$('#menu li About').removeClass('classname');
```

and

```
$('#menu li').attr(About).removeClass('classname');
```

and

```
if ($('#menu li').attr("id") == "About")
  $('#menu li').removeClass('classname');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close.  This code:

```
$('#menu li About')
```

Is looking for an element of id `menu` which contains an element named `li` which contains an element *named* `About`.  You need to specify that it's another id (and is an id on the `li`):

```
$('#menu li#About')
```

Of course, since ids are *supposed to be* unique within the document, this *should* work just as well:

```
$('#About')
```

Answer (score 3):

your selector is wrong. select the id you need. try:

```
('#About').removeClass('classname');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#menu li#About').removeClass('classname');
```

or just

```
$('li#About').removeClass('classname');
```

or

```
$('#About').removeClass('classname');
```

or

```
$('#About', '#menu').removeClass('classname');
```

Answer (score 1):

please make yourself familiar with the way jQuery Selectors work ( http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ ).

What you are looking for is the ID selector, which you do use on the `#menu`-Part, thus `$('#About')` would be the correct selector.